# Подключение разных пакетов API не влияет на размер подгружаемых файлов JS

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подключаю api карт с полным пакетом через https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?load=package.full в итоге грузится js-файл https://yastatic.net/s3/front-maps-static/front-jsapi-v2-1/2.1.77-27/build/release/full-d3f34cc99c9c0dd436b9bc268e8dd6c17d0c711a.js размером 709кб.

Далее подключаю пакет search (который по данным документации https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/packages-docpage/ значительно меньше по функционалу) в надежде уменьшить размер библиотеки. Подключаю api с помощью https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?load=package.search&lang=ru_RU. В инспекторе загрузки вижу тот же файл размером 709кб.

Как можно уменьшить размер подключаемого api, если используется только простая карта, или независимо от загружаемого пакета, размер будет 709кб, что существенно в рамках мобильного сайта?

package.full: https://yadi.sk/i/SXGKIlmFKKTByQ

package.search: https://yadi.sk/i/Hygtmta5VCUg2A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с версии 2.1.77 Яндекс отказался от модульной системы в текущем виде в пользу статических бандлов кода с вечным кешированием.

По факту это даёт больший выигрыш в оптимизации загрузки API, чем модульная система, которая в большинстве случаёв всё равно приводила к выкачиванию полного кода API, но без полноценного кеширования.

Теперь пользователю достаточно на любом сайте скачать API, чтобы на вашем код был взят из кеша.

Comment: Инструменты по анализу быстродействия сайта не используют кэш, соответственно рейтинг всегда будет занижен. По анализу lighthouse основную часть времени исполнения js это именно этот статичный бандл. Поисковые системы заявили о том, что оптимизация сайта будет учитываться при ранжировании, и если поисковые роботы тоже не будут учитывать кэш, то позиции в выдаче будут порезаны из-за сервиса самой поисковой системы, иронично.

Comment: >>Начиная с версии 2.1.77 Яндекс отказался от модульной системы в текущем виде в пользу статических бандлов кода с вечным кешированием. Есть ли официальный пруф?
https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/api-yandeks-kart-versiya-2-1-77
Тут про это ничего не говорится

Comment: Это письменный ответ поддержки API Яндекс.Карт на вопрос, аналогичный этому. Документация до сих пор не исправлена - да, но у них часто задержки с её правками, так что придётся поверить на слово. Можете самостоятельно переспросить у поддержки, если не верите - maps-api@support.yandex.ru